# Temperature conversion program c++

Tags: c++, class, temperature

I have been trying to write a temperature conversion program to teach myself how the class system in c++ which will convert any given temperature input (Celsius, Fahrenheit and kelvin) to the other two values then output all three values again. However I am unable to get my project to compile and I am too much of a rookie to find the errors myself. (Believe me I have tried all day). 
If someone could please take a look at it and make any suggestions/improvements I would greatly appreciate it. 
Apologies for not writing any comments into my code by the way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Temperature
{
private:
    const double ConversionRate = 0.55555;
    const double AbsoluteZero = 273.15;
    const int TemperatureOffset = 32;

    double InputTemperature = 0;
    double Fahrenheit = 0, Celsius = 0, Kelvin = 0;

public:
    bool setTemperature(double temperature, char temperatureformat)
    {
        bool temperatureConfigured = true;
        if (temperatureformat == 'c') {
            Celsius = temperature;
            Fahrenheit = ((1 / ConversionRate)*(Celsius)) + TemperatureOffset;
            Kelvin = Celsius + AbsoluteZero;
        }
        else if (temperatureformat == 'f') {
            Fahrenheit = temperature;
            Celsius = (ConversionRate*(Fahrenheit - TemperatureOffset));
            Kelvin = (Celsius + AbsoluteZero);
        }
        else if (temperatureformat == 'k') {
            if (temperature >= 0)
            {
                Kelvin = temperature;
                Celsius = Kelvin - AbsoluteZero;
                Fahrenheit = (1 / ConversionRate)*Celsius + TemperatureOffset;
            }
            else {
                temperatureConfigured = false;
                Celsius = 0;
                Kelvin = 0;
                Fahrenheit = 0;

            }
        }
        else {
            temperatureConfigured = false;
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        double InputReading = 0;
        Temperature temperatureCalculator;
        char temperatureformat = NULL;

        cout << "Please Enter your temperature value" << endl;
        cin >> InputReading;
        cout << "Celsius        - c" << endl;
        cout << "Fahrenheit     - f" << endl;
        cout << "Kelvin         - k" << endl;
        cin >> temperatureformat;


        if (temperatureCalculator.setTemperature (InputReading, temperatureformat)) {
            cout << "Your temperature conversions are" << endl;
            cout << "Celsius:    " << temperatureCalculator.getCelsius() << endl;
            cout << "Fahrenheit: " << temperatureCalculator.getFahrenheit << endl;
            cout << "Kelvin:     " << temperatureCalculator.getKelvin << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Error, your input was invalid" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Compilation errors are as follows:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error (active)      class "Temperature" has no member "getCelsius"  69
Error (active)      class "Temperature" has no member "getFahrenheit" 70
Error (active)      class "Temperature" has no member "getKelvin"   71
Error (active)      expected a ';'  77
Error   C1004   unexpected end-of-file found    78
```

Comment: A list of the compilation errors with line numbers would help

Comment: start with putting main outside the class

Comment: _`class "Temperature" has no member "getCelsius"`_ - so can you add a member `getCelsius`?

Comment: A class needs a `;` at the end of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems:

- Unlike java, `main` will be separate from the class.
- You were missing `get` methods that you were trying to use.
- You had several typos.
- I'm not sure if you actually want private constants. Macros would make more sense.

Anyway, here's the code (that compiles). It's untested, so that's left as an exercise for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Temperature
{
private:
    const double ConversionRate = 0.55555;
    const double AbsoluteZero = 273.15;
    const int TemperatureOffset = 32;

    double InputTemperature = 0;
    double Fahrenheit = 0, Celsius = 0, Kelvin = 0;

public:
    double getFahrenheit() { return Fahrenheit; }
    double getCelsius() { return Celsius; }
    double getKelvin() { return Kelvin; }
    bool setTemperature(double temperature, char temperatureformat)
    {
        bool temperatureConfigured = true;
        if (temperatureformat == 'c') {
            Celsius = temperature;
            Fahrenheit = ((1 / ConversionRate)*(Celsius)) + TemperatureOffset;
            Kelvin = Celsius + AbsoluteZero;
        }
        else if (temperatureformat == 'f') {
            Fahrenheit = temperature;
            Celsius = (ConversionRate*(Fahrenheit - TemperatureOffset));
            Kelvin = (Celsius + AbsoluteZero);
        }
        else if (temperatureformat == 'k') {
            if (temperature >= 0)
            {
                Kelvin = temperature;
                Celsius = Kelvin - AbsoluteZero;
                Fahrenheit = (1 / ConversionRate)*Celsius + TemperatureOffset;
            }
            else {
                temperatureConfigured = false;
                Celsius = 0;
                Kelvin = 0;
                Fahrenheit = 0;

            }
        }
        else {
            temperatureConfigured = false;
        }
    }

};

int main()
    {
        double InputReading = 0;
        Temperature temperatureCalculator;
        char temperatureformat = NULL;

        cout << "Please Enter your temperature value" << endl;
        cin >> InputReading;
        cout << "Celsius        - c" << endl;
        cout << "Fahrenheit     - f" << endl;
        cout << "Kelvin         - k" << endl;
        cin >> temperatureformat;


        if (temperatureCalculator.setTemperature (InputReading, temperatureformat)) {
            cout << "Your temperature conversions are" << endl;
            cout << "Celsius:    " << temperatureCalculator.getCelsius() << endl;
            cout << "Fahrenheit: " << temperatureCalculator.getFahrenheit() << endl;
            cout << "Kelvin:     " << temperatureCalculator.getKelvin() << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Error, your input was invalid" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that `setTemperature` doesn't return anything - this will be a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much... really appreciate you taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
if (temperatureCalculator, setTemperature (InputReading, temperatureformat))
```

Seems suspicious to me. Why is there a comma between `temperatureCalculator` and `setTemperature`? Did you mean to have a 'dot' (`.`) to instead call the class method `setTemperature` on your `Temperature` class instance `temperatureCalculator`?

If you post the actual error, we can help more. Good luck!

Comment: Yes thanks very much that was a mistake on my part. I replaced the comma with a dot there however it has made no change to the error messages that I am receiving from the compiler. :/

Comment: As the others mentioned, you will need to

- put a semi colon `;` at the end of the class definition (in the code posted above, this is immediately following the closing brace `}` on your last line
- cut and paste your `main` block to be outside of the class definition (put `main` below the class definition)  
- make definitions in the class for `getCelsius`, `getFahrenheit`, and `getKelvin` -- they can be empty for now, but write a skeleton for each one to make the compiler happy

Answer (score 1):

This line, maybe?

```
if (temperatureCalculator, setTemperature (InputReading, temperatureformat))
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that comma there. You probably want to put a period instead. You also need to put semicolons at the end of your class (after the last curly bracket). And finally, you should put your main method at the end of the file, outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You had many problems with your code:

1. Change conversion constants to `static` (not really a problem, but warns with C++03)
2. Initialize local variables in constructor, not in class definition. (warns in C++03)
3. Define getters for local variables.
4. Return a value from `setTemperature()`.
5. Move definition of `main()` outside the class.
6. Add a semicolon after the class definition.
7. Change `int main()` to `int main(void)`.
8. Use `char temperatureformat = 0` instead of `char temperatureformat = NULL`.
9. Change `, setTemperature` to `.setTemperature`.
10. Add parentheses after function names (required).
11. Add a return value for `main()`.

All of them are comments prefixed by `CHANGE:`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Temperature
{
private:
    // CHANGE: DECLARE STATIC
    static const double ConversionRate = 0.55555;
    static const double AbsoluteZero = 273.15;
    static const int TemperatureOffset = 32;

    // CHANGE: USE CONSTRUCTOR BELOW INSTEAD FOR INITIALIZATION
    double InputTemperature;
    double Fahrenheit, Celsius, Kelvin;

public:
    // CHANGE: DEFINE CONSTRUCTOR
    Temperature() : InputTemperature(0), Fahrenheit(0), Celsius(0), Kelvin(0) {}

    // CHANGE: DEFINE GETTERS
    double getFahrenheit() const {return Fahrenheit;}
    double getCelsius() const {return Celsius;}
    double getKelvin() const {return Kelvin;}

    bool setTemperature(double temperature, char temperatureformat)
    {
        bool temperatureConfigured = true;
        if (temperatureformat == 'c') {
            Celsius = temperature;
            Fahrenheit = ((1 / ConversionRate)*(Celsius)) + TemperatureOffset;
            Kelvin = Celsius + AbsoluteZero;
        }
        else if (temperatureformat == 'f') {
            Fahrenheit = temperature;
            Celsius = (ConversionRate*(Fahrenheit - TemperatureOffset));
            Kelvin = (Celsius + AbsoluteZero);
        }
        else if (temperatureformat == 'k') {
            if (temperature >= 0)
            {
                Kelvin = temperature;
                Celsius = Kelvin - AbsoluteZero;
                Fahrenheit = (1 / ConversionRate)*Celsius + TemperatureOffset;
            }
            else {
                temperatureConfigured = false;
                Celsius = 0;
                Kelvin = 0;
                Fahrenheit = 0;

            }
        }
        else {
            temperatureConfigured = false;
        }

        // CHANGE: RETURN VALUE
        return temperatureConfigured;
    }

    // CHANGE: MOVE main() OUTSIDE CLASS
}; // CHANGE: ADD SEMICOLON AFTER CLASS

// CHANGE: MAKE int main(void)
int main(void)
{
    double InputReading = 0;
    Temperature temperatureCalculator;
    // CHANGE: MAKE 0, NOT NULL
    char temperatureformat = 0;

    cout << "Please Enter your temperature value" << endl;
    cin >> InputReading;
    cout << "Celsius        - c" << endl;
    cout << "Fahrenheit     - f" << endl;
    cout << "Kelvin         - k" << endl;
    cin >> temperatureformat;

    // CHANGE: USE . MEMBER ACCESS OPERATOR
    if (temperatureCalculator.setTemperature (InputReading, temperatureformat)) {
        cout << "Your temperature conversions are" << endl;
        cout << "Celsius:    " << temperatureCalculator.getCelsius() << endl;
        // CHANGE: ADD PARENTHESES AFTER FUNCTION NAMES
        cout << "Fahrenheit: " << temperatureCalculator.getFahrenheit() << endl;
        cout << "Kelvin:     " << temperatureCalculator.getKelvin() << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error, your input was invalid" << endl;
    }

    // CHANGE: RETURN VALUE
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some functions definitions to your class in addition with `;` at end of class:

> Error (active)      class "Temperature" has no member "getCelsius"  69

```
double getCelsius()
    {
        return Celsius;
    }
```

> Error (active)      class "Temperature" has no member "getFahrenheit" 70

```
double getFahrenheit()
{
    return Fahrenheit;
}
```

> Error (active)      class "Temperature" has no member "getKelvin"   71

```
double getKelvin()
{
    return Kelvin;
}
```